# Error when send two or more SMS`s

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using the Cordova SMS plugin to send messages from an application developed with Ionic. When the "friends" array has length = 1 a SMS is sent. But when you have more than that, sometimes the messages do not arrive, or worse, the same number gets two messages. Is there something wrong with this code?
The problematic part of the code is as follows:

```
$rootScope.showLoading('Enviando mensagen(s)!');

var loopPromises = [];

$rootScope.friends = [{
            nome: 'David',
            telefone: '83777777777'
        }, {
            nome: 'Edvan',
            telefone: '83444444444'
        }, {
            nome: 'Débora',
            telefone: '83888888888'
        }]

var interno = {
      nome: "#App",
      telefone: "83222222222"
}
$rootScope.friends.push(interno)

angular.forEach($rootScope.friends, function (a) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  loopPromises.push(deferred.promise);
  var texto = '';
  if (a.telefone == "83222222222") {
    texto = "Internal report"
    $rootScope.friends.pop();
  } else {
    texto = "Hello! I'm here!"
  }

  $cordovaSms.send(a.telefone, texto)
    .then(deferred.resolve, deferred.reject);
});

$q.all(loopPromises).then(function (results) {
  $rootScope.hideLoading();
  $rootScope.showToast('Messages sent!');
  }, function (errors) {
  $rootScope.hideLoading();
  $rootScope.showToast('Some message was not sent!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code on your **config.xml**

```
<access origin="sms:*" launch-external="yes"/>
```

I hope this helps.

**OR**

make some changes on

```
var options = {
        replaceLineBreaks: false, // true to replace \n by a new line, false by default
        android: {
            intent: 'INTENT'  // send SMS with the native android SMS messaging
            //intent: '' // send SMS without open any other app
        }
    };

for(var j=0;j<$rootScope.friends.length;j++){

    var texto = '';
    if (a.telefone == "83222222222") {
         texto = "Internal report"
         $rootScope.friends.pop();
    } else {
     texto = "Hello! I'm here!"
    }

    $cordovaSms
    .send($rootScope.friends[0].telefone, texto', options)
    .then(function() {
         console.log('Success');
     }, function(error) {
         alert('Not Sent'); // An error occurred
     });
}
```

Comment: I have added option filed and made some changes. Please try once and let me know.